# What certificates/profiles should I back up?

Tags: ios, xcode

Ive read that it is very important to back up your private key(?) for your developer account, because it can not be recreated if my computer crash or I need to develop on a new computer. Ive done some googling, but I cant figure out what files it is I need to back up. Is it the profile in xcode>preferences>Accounts? or is it something in keychanin?

Below is how my keychain looks like, why do I have multiple keys?!

What files should I back up to be safe? Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is 2 different ways to backup your private keys.

The first one is:

If you are using Xcode 5 or Xcode 6, you can go to `Xcode > Preferences > Accounts` and `Export accounts...`. This will exports all your information:

- Account information
- All Certificates with the associated **private keys**
- All Provisioning profiles

Then you can save the generated file where you want. To use this backup, go to `Xcode > Preferences > Accounts` and `Import accounts...` and select your backup file.

This is the simplest way.

---

The second way is:

If you want to only save a specific certificate with its associated **private key**, you can go to `Keychain > Certificates` then expand the certificate you want to export to see its private key below, select both the certificate and the private key, right click and then `Export 2 items`. Choose the `.p12` file format. The file created can be imported again simply by open it, it will launch `Keychain`to store your certificate and its private key again.

PS: for your keys in your keychain, they are related to one or more files and are used to encrypt/decrypt them.